# 1D CNN with 3D Kernel kernel

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to tarin a 1D CNN using hyperspectral images with 2402 bands. I want to use a patch size of 5x5x2404. My training data has the dimensions of (1035, 2402, 5, 5), since I have 1035 samples.

My question is, what is the correct input_shape for my first Conv1D layer?

I have respahed my data to 1035x2404x5x5 but that didn't really help. Trying:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=50, activation='relu', input_shape=(2402, 5, 5)))
```

results in an error:

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_38: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4.

- So my question is, are 1D CNNs from keras not usable for HSI images with 3D patches?
- If they are, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you post the first layer? The error message suggests that the error is with another conv1D layer

Comment: Yes, do you mean because of the number 38? I am using jupyter notebook. This number risis by 1, everytime I run my code.